# Is there any example/demo/reference related push notification using kafka in spring boot(backend) and react(frontend) project

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Want to implement push notifications functionality in my spring boot and react project
Is there any examples or references then please share

I tried some solutions but most part it uses WebSocket but i want push notifications using kafka in spring boot and react

Answer (score 0):

Kafka isn't an HTTP service, therefore you are required to pair WebSockets or SSE from a backend service to any frontend.

You can also pull rather than push. Related term from Kafka is "Interactive Queries" - https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/interactive-queries/